# validating array objects in active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

pls anyone help me to do validation in array of object...weightage is my field name..i just want to validate(presence and  numericality) the weightage.but i could not get any validaation errors..i dont know at whivh place i did the mistake..if anyone knows the solution pls let me know

This is my view:

```
<tbody>             
            <% if @company_column_master != nil then                            
                @company_column_master.each.with_index(0) do |assess,index| %>
                  <tr> 
                    <td><%= index+1 %> 
                        <%= hidden_field_tag :company_column_master_id ,assess.attributes["company_column_master_id"],name: 'cd_column_id[]' %>
                        <%= hidden_field_tag :data_element_id ,assess.attributes["data_element_id"],name: 'data_element_id[]' %>
                        <%= hidden_field_tag :display_order ,assess.attributes["display_order"],name: 'display_order[]' %>
                    </td>       
                    <td><%= text_field_tag "display_name", assess.attributes["display_name"], name: 'display_name[]', size:50 ,:autocomplete => :off%></td>
                    <td><%= text_field_tag "weightage", assess.attributes["weightage"] ,name: 'weightage[]' ,:autocomplete => :off%></td>                                           #getting values from db using array
                    <td class="text-center">
                        <%= check_box_tag('status'+index.to_s,'1',if (assess.attributes["status"] == 1) then true end, class: 'js-switch') %>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                <%end%>
                <%= hidden_field_tag :phase_id ,@company_column_master[0].attributes["cd_phase_id"]%>
                <%= hidden_field_tag :phase_detail_id ,@company_column_master[0].attributes["cd_phase_detail_id"]%>         
            <%end%>
        </tbody>
```

This is my model part:

```
class CompanyColumnMaster < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :weightage, :presence => {:message => 'cannot be Blank!'}, :format => {:with => /\A[0-9]+\z/, message: "may only contain numbers."}, 
  :length => {:maximum => 50, :message => 'Exceeds Maximum number of numbers.'}

  validate :check_weightage

 def check_weightage
   if weightage!=nil && weightage < 0
     errors.add(:weightage, "should be greater than or equal to zero")
   end
 end
end
```

Comment: You are messing with the validations.May be should have at these [**Guides**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html)

Comment: Sorry i do not understand what you are saying..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing 2 thing at the same time - you use Rails' `validates` and custom `validate`. Choose one.

In order to use custom validation you have to write the method (what you've done almost Ok):

```
validate :check_weightage

def check_weightage
   errors.add(:weightage, "should be greater than or equal to zero") unless (weightage && weightage >= 0 && weightage.is_a? Integer)
end
```

Comment: yeah i have tried this too..but really am not getting solution. or Should i use [] in model too?? like 
def check_weightage
   errors.add(:weightage[], "should be greater than or equal to zero") unless (weightage[] && weightage[] >= 0 && weightage.is_a? Integer) because am displaying the weightage values using array right?? so that am asking
end

Comment: what I've wrote should work, but you have to remove validates line

Comment: i have removed that line and wrote your code..but it shows 
unexpected constant" error

Comment: i have got the error in my model "Unexpected tConstant"in line 22

Comment: and which line is that? does it intercepts with the method I've written?

Comment: i have got the same error which i mentioned in my last comment

Comment: which line that 22 exactly is?

Comment: errors.add(:weightage, "should be greater than or equal to zero") unless (weightage && weightage >= 0 && weightage.is_a? Integer)

Comment: it is probably an issue with the attribute name. how did you name the attribute in database?

Comment: "weightage" only buddy...that issues refers the constant name..i didnt use constant..

Comment: exactly the reason why it is strange. don't see why it raises error

Comment: ok buddy..thanks for your valuable comment..let me try..thanks a lot